# how to set a UIImageView tintColor from another image pattern color in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uicolor

I am looking to set the `UIImageView` `tintColor` from a `UIColor` pattern image. So far it works perfect with `UILabels`

```
let image = UIImage(named: "my_pattern_image")
let pattarnColor = UIColor(patternImage: image)

let newImage = UIImage(named: "some_template_image").withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
let imageView = UIImageView(image: newImage)
imageView.tintColor = pattarnColor
```

The above works well with `UILabels`, as well as testing the rendering mode, setting the color to `UIColor.red` and image changes the tintColor. It just doesn't work with pattern image color for some reason, and sets this to white.

[image]

Comment: For me everything works as expected: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpRiV.png

Comment: Thanks @AndréSlotta but this doesn't work for me. I followed step by step on playground and this doesn't work. Can you please try with my images? https://www.dropbox.com/sh/za45mi3a4aqqcbh/AAD8F8w2Gy-ahjyt3AIkHZiKa?dl=1

Comment: Still works as expected: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xUB9.png

Comment: Really strange, did you test this also on Swift 4.0? Check out my result: https://www.dropbox.com/s/kzrzj96cza6k4n5/Screen%20Shot%202018-01-28%20at%2018.00.38.png?dl=0

Comment: ok. same problem here with Xcode 9.2.

Comment: Might be a bug. I do not see any change from Swift 3 to 4 that could cause this issue...

Comment: did you get any solution? @TalZion